# Is the limit of $\left(\sum_{i=-n}^{i=n} \tanh(x - i)\right)-2x$ a sine wave?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I have been plotting functions of the form 
$$\left(\sum_{i=-n}^{i=n} \tanh(x - i)\right)-2x$$
which, over the region around zero, look a lot like sine waves. For example, here's the function for $n=10$.

[image]

Empirically, it seems to be something approximating $0.00065 \sin(2 \pi x)$.
Beyond about $n=10$ it is very stable over the region $x\in[-5,5]$, as you might expect from $\tanh(x)$ being approximately $\pm 1$ for large $\pm x$. I have found plots of the series and $0.00065 \sin(2 \pi x)$ are indistinguishable. Here's the same plot zoomed out with this sine wave in orange:

[image]

Is this actually tending towards a sine wave? and if so, what is the exact value 
 of the constant $k$ in

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum_{i=-n}^{i=n} \tanh(x - i)\right)-2x = k \sin(2 \pi x)$$

**Update**

I've calculated the specific values of this function symbolically with Mathematica, and evaluated it with $N[.,100]$ function at x=1/4, 5/4, 401/4 and 4001/4 which gives

```
   1/4: 0.0006499727271926147575932558139650291715585570399687299381104388139877502424025845538796044013975974138
   5/4: 0.0006499727271926147575932558139650291715585570399687299381104388139877502424025845538796044013975974138
 401/4: 0.0006499727271926147575932558139650291715585570399687299381104388139877502424025845538796044013975974138
4001/4: 0.0006499727271926147575932558139650291715585570399687299381104388139877502424025845538796044013975974138
```

I'm not 100% sure this is not a numerical issue, but I also don't see any reason why it should be 0.00065 exactly either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have the following expansion:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \tanh(x+k) = 2x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\pi}{\sinh(\pi^2 k)} \sin(2\pi k x). \tag{*} $$

So the resulting function is not a pure sine function, but since the coefficients decay exponentially fast, the first term is predominant. This can also be glimpsed from the following numerical value:

$$ \frac{2\pi}{\sinh(\pi^2)} \approx 0.000649972728931478984525468377615\cdots, $$

---

**Derivation of the identity $\text{(*)}$.**

1. Assume for a moment that not only the LHS of $\text{(*)}$ converges, but it is also differentiable and can be computed by interchanging the order of limiting operators:

   \begin{align*}
   \frac{d}{dx}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \tanh(x+k)
   &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \frac{d}{dx}\tanh(x+k) \\
   &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x+k)}.
   \end{align*}

   (We will justify this later, but at this point this is just a technical issue.) The summand of the last sum has exponential decay as $k\to\infty$, so we can use the [*Poisson summation formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) to obtain

   $$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x+k)}
   = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f(k)
   = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(k). $$

   To evaluate the last sum, we appeal to the following well-known result

   $$ \hat{f}(\xi) = e^{2\pi i \xi x} \frac{2\pi^2 \xi}{\sinh(\pi^2 \xi)}, \qquad \hat{f}(0) = 2. $$

   Plugging this back, we have

   $$ \frac{d}{dx}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \tanh(x+k)
   = 2 + \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{4\pi^2 k}{\sinh(\pi^2 k)} e^{2\pi i k x}. $$

   Integrating both sides and using the fact that the LHS of $\text{(*)}$ vanishes at $x = 0$, we have

   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \tanh(x+k)
   &= 2x + \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{2\pi}{i \sinh(\pi^2 k)} e^{2\pi i k x} \\
   &= 2x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\pi}{\sinh(\pi^2 k)} \sin(2\pi k x)
   \end{align*}

   as expected.
2. We justify that the limit and differentiation can be exchanged. This is in fact not hard:

   \begin{align*}
   \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \tanh(x+k)
   &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} [\tanh(k+x) - \tanh(k-x)] \\
   &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{du}{\cosh^2(u+k)} \\
   &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-x}^{x} \left( \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \frac{1}{\cosh^2(u+k)} \right) \, du.
   \end{align*}

   Since the integrand of the last integral converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to an *even* function, it follows that

   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n} \tanh(x+k)
   &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-x}^{x} \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh^2(u+k)} \right) \, du \\
   &= \int_{0}^{x} \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh^2(u+k)} \right) \, du.
   \end{align*}

   This is precisely what we needed to justify in the previous computation.

Comment: Ah, Fourier transform... obvious in hindsight. Thanks very much, this problem was really bugging me.